# Unable to find UIApplicationShortcutIcon.init(contact: CNContact) for loading contact image in dynamic action

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cncontact

That's really weird that there is no `init(contact: CNContact)` inside `UIApplicationShortcutIcon`, this is recently released and not even deprecated.

[image]

There are only two options, `init` with `type` and `templateImageName`. Whereas when I check `UIApplicationShortcutIcon` api reference at Apple, it's showing it's available.

[image]

Comment: You need to `import ContactsUI` to use `UIApplicationShortcutIcon.init(contact:)`. (Though, Apple's doc is not clear enough about it.)

Comment: Please write your comment in answer, So I can up vote it to help others.

Comment: Please take some time to post it by yourself. You know you can accept your own answer (after a while).

Comment: Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [@OOPer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6541007/ooper) comment, You need to import ContactsUI to use UIApplicationShortcutIcon.init(contact:). (Though, Apple's doc is not clear enough about it.)

Comment: From the Overview section of the [UIApplicationShortcutIcon API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationshortcuticon): "An icon representing a contact in the user's address book, which you access through the ContactsUI framework (see ContactsUI)"

Comment: Having used `Contacts` and `ContactsUI`, I knew that a `CNContact` would require `Contacts`, but their use of "access through" is not entirely clear.